# JavaScript: Is there a way to fire an javascript function remotely? Like an onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, request

I'm looking for a way to fire an JavaScript event in a remote web page without opening it on browser.

I mean, let-me explain my situation:
What I do now is, I have two scripts running on GreaseMonkey at specific web pages.
Script A on page A, Script B on page B.

The script A keeps sending xmlHttpRequests to page B, it gets the data, process in a reg-exp, and make some comparisons. When my condition on Script A is satisfied, I send an window.open to open page B.

On page B, I have the script B running, the script B check the content of page B again, see if the SAME condition of script A is satisfied, making a double check, and then fire the click events that I need.

The problem is, too slow. I need to optimize it.
Is too slow to open the Page B and load it's contents, like lot's of images, backgrounds, css styles, etc. It takes some seconds to load the page, between 5 to 10 seconds, to be precise. I need it to be under 1 or 2 seconds.

Is there a way to fire JavaScript events on page B, without loading the whole content of page B?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not reliably.

You could set up a node instance to request the page, and run server-side JavaScript against the http response, but that wouldn't be anything like running a script in a browser window that can interact with the scripts that the page runs, and the assets it pulls in from other URLs.

To fire an event on a page it would have to be loaded into a browser. You could speed things up with [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) or another headless browser though.

I'd recommend the latter if you want performance and quality over greasemonkey any day. It's a little more complex, but if this is an ongoing comparison automating it into the background and away from a rendering browser seems best.

Comment: I've done some things with phantom already, but without many success, then I quitted after spend too many time into a little problem. The problem was that I must be logged in on Page B, then, I failed doing it on Phantom, maybe I need to try it again, and put more efforts there.
As you said and I agree, it would be awsome without a rendering browser.

Answer (score 0):

my solution may not be perfect, but you could do the next (as you ar on GreaseMonkey)

1- XMLHTTPrequest page B

2- make the comparison

3- if satisfied, put the innerHTML you got from the first XMLHTTPrequest into a new div/iframe you create and make invisible

4- there you can run the click event into that div/iframe

Comment: I don't know if it works, cause I don't own Page B scripts. I mean, I can create the div, the elements, but what about the scripts Page B runs when the element get clicked?

Comment: i gess even the headers and the scripts are returned by the server. put those in a iframe element, and it should work.